# Check OS or platform via web Pixel Streaming on Unreal Engine?

Tags: deployment, unreal-engine5

I have a UE5.1 project deployed as a Pixel Streaming app. I want to be able to detect the users platform or operating system. Since the game is being rendered on a server and not natively, is there a way to communicate to the engine about the users system ? I want it so I can offer different controls and interface for users on touch UI compared to KBM UIs.